# Forward declaration of lambdas in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, declaration, definition

In C++, it is possible to separate the declaration and definition of functions. For example, it is quite normal to declare a function:

```
int Foo(int x);
```

in `Foo.h` and implement it in `Foo.cpp`. Is it possible to do something similar with lambdas? For example, define a

```
std::function<int(int)> bar;
```

in `bar.h` and implement it in `bar.cpp` as:

```
std::function<int(int)> bar = [](int n)
{
    if (n >= 5) 
        return n;
    return n*(n + 1);
};
```

**Disclaimer**: I have experience with lambdas in C#, but I have not used them in C++ very much.

Comment: If you're going to give the lambda a name, you may as well just make it a normal function.

Comment: @Brian I know and it makes sense. The main reason that I ask the question is curiosity and I like to know the possibility of it.

Comment: FYI; `std::function<int(int)>` is able to store lambdas; but lambdas do not have the type `std::function<...>`; but rather have their own unique unnamed type. You can store a lambda directly in a variable if the type of that variable is deduced (either via `auto` or template argument type deduction). `std::function` has a template constructor that is able to take a lambda argument via this principle of template argument type deduction.

Comment: Let's look at this: int b; b = 13; You declare names, not literals. How would you declare 13, and why? Your lambda is like 13 and `bar` is like `b`.

Comment: @Mankarse Interesting fact that I did not know. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, the distinction is the same in C#. You appear to be confusing (C#) delegates with (C#) lambdas (essentially: 'anonymous delegate implementations'). In C#, lambdas can be assigned to delegates (variables) but they are not the same thing, just like in C++.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can't separate declaration and definition of [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Explanation), neither forward declare it. Its type is a unique unnamed closure type which is declared with the lambda expression. But you could do that with [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) objects, which is designed to be able to store any callable target, including lambdas.

As your sample code shown you've been using `std::function`, just note that for this case `bar` is a global variable indeed, and you need to use `extern` in header file to make it a declaration (not a definition).

```
// bar.h
extern std::function<int(int)> bar;     // declaration
```

and

```
// bar.cpp
std::function<int(int)> bar = [](int n) // definition
{
    if (n >= 5) return n;
    return n*(n + 1);
};
```

Note again that this is not separate declaration and definition of lambda; It's just separate declaration and definition of a global variable `bar` with type `std::function<int(int)>`, which is initialized from a lambda expression.

Comment: @Mzhr note that the type of a lambda is not std::function, but an unnamed type unique to the lambda. std::function is a polymorphic wrapper around any callable object.

Answer (score 10):

Forward declaration is not the correct term because lambdas in C++ are objects, not functions. The code:

```
std::function<int(int)> bar;
```

declares a variable and you're not forced to assign it (that type has a default value of "pointer to no function"). You can compile even calls to it... for example the code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    std::function<int(int)> bar;
    std::cout << bar(21) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

will compile cleanly (but of course will behave crazily at runtime).

That said you can assign a lambda to a compatible `std::function` variable and adding for example:

```
bar = [](int x){ return x*2; };
```

right before the call will result in a program that compiles fine and generates as output 42.

A few non-obvious things that can be surprising about lambdas in C++ (if you know other languages that have this concept) are that

- Each lambda `[..](...){...}` has a different incompatible type, even if the signature is absolutely identical. You for example cannot declare a parameter of lambda type because the only way would be to use something like `decltype([] ...)` but then there would be no way to call the function as any other `[]...` form at a call site would be incompatible. This is solved by `std::function` so if you have to pass lambdas around or store them in containers you must use `std::function`.
- Lambdas can capture locals by value (but they're `const` unless you declare the lambda `mutable`) or by reference (but guaranteeing the lifetime of the referenced object will not be shorter than the lifetime of the lambda is up to the programmer). C++ has no garbage collector and this is something needed to solve correctly the "upward funarg" problem (you can work-around by capturing smart pointers, but you must pay attention to reference loops to avoid leaks).
- Differently from other languages lambdas can be copied and when you copy them you're taking a snapshot of their internal captured by-value variables. This can be very surprising for mutable state and this is I think the reason for which captured by-value values are `const` by default.

A way to rationalize and remember many of the details about lambdas is that code like:

```
std::function<int(int)> timesK(int k) {
    return [k](int x){ return x*k; };
}
```

is basically like

```
std::function<int(int)> timesK(int k) {
    struct __Lambda6502 {
        int k;
        __Lambda6502(int k) : k(k) {}
        int operator()(int x) {
            return x * k;
        }
    };
    return __Lambda6502(k);
}
```

with one subtle difference that even lambda capturing references can be copied (normally classes containing references as members cannot).

Answer (score 9):

Strictly speaking you can't

Quoting from [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

> The lambda expression is a prvalue expression whose value is (until
>   C++17)whose result object is (since C++17) an unnamed temporary object
>   of unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate class type, known as closure
>   type, which is declared (for the purposes of ADL) in the smallest
>   block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the lambda
>   expression

So the lambda is a **unnamed temporary object**. You can bind the lambda to a l-value object(for eg `std::function`) and by regular rules about variable declaration you can separate the declaration and definition.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. May I ask about the source of your quote? Is it from a C++ specification?